# InaccessibleObjectException with java.lang module

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-17

I'm running into issue starting a Sprnigboot app on Intellij Idea. I'm using Springboot 3.x and JDK 17. I have a bean that is requested scoped that is causing issues at startup.

I have tried to set the option on jvm arguments as described in bunch of resources but none of that seems to work. I have set the arguments in both pom.xml but also in the IntelliJ run configuration. When I run the application main method, I get the InaccessibleException.

**MydemoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MydemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MydemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**MyAppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfig {

    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    public Object myObject(){
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mydemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mydemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Stacktrace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myObject' defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [com/example/mydemo/MyAppConfig.class]: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class java.lang.Object: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:605) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at com.example.mydemo.MydemoApplication.main(MydemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class java.lang.Object: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.buildProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:222) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:155) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean.setBeanFactory(ScopedProxyFactoryBean.java:115) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1791) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1060b431
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:547) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:371) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:575) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.lambda$new$1(AbstractClassGenerator.java:107) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.lambda$createEntry$1(LoadingCache.java:52) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:57) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:130) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:317) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:562) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:407) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:62) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.buildProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1060b431
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:505) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Idea run configuration
[image]

Comment: What `cglib` is doing here is fundamentally not possible on JDK17. Upgrade cglib, or if it's at the newest version, downgrade your JDK, or if that's not an option either, find another library that does that. Last resort is a bevy of `--add-opens` but that's kinda hackish.

Comment: @Holger I mentioned spring-boot 3.1 in my post. That's the latest version of springboot. It has dependency on spring framework 6.x

Comment: Ok, I’ll stick to the facts as presented by the stack trace. This version of a software whose packages start with `org.springframework` is clearly not Java 17 compatible.